# Using XPath to parse an XML document

Tags: c#, xpath, xmldocument

Lets say I have the following xml (a quick example)

```
<rows>
   <row>
      <name>one</name>
   </row>
   <row>
      <name>two</name>
   </row>
</rows>
```

I am trying to parse this by using XmlDocument and XPath (ultimately so I can make a list of rows).

For example...

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

foreach(XmlNode row in doc.SelectNodes("//row"))
{
   string rowName = row.SelectSingleNode("//name").InnerText;
}
```

Why, within my foreach loop, is rowName always "one"? I am expecting it to be "one" on the first iteration and "two" on the second.

It seems that //name gets the first instance in the document, rather than the first instance in the row as I would expect. After all, I am calling the method on the "row" node. If this is "just how it works" then can anybody please explain how I could change it to work to my needs?

Thank you

Comment: how about selecting it by //row/name? Does this work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

foreach(XmlNode row in doc.SelectNodes("//row"))
{
   var rowName = row.SelectSingleNode("name");
}
```

Is the code you posted actually correct?  I get a compile error on row.SelectNode() as it isn't a member of XmlNode.

Anyway, my example above works, but assumes only a single `<name>` node within the `<row>` node so you may need to use `SelectNodes()` instead of `SelectSingleNode()` if that is not the case.

As others have shown, use `.InnerText` to get just the value.

Answer (score 5):

Use LINQ to XML. Include `using System.Xml.Linq;` in your code file and then do the following code to get your list

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
IEnumerable<XElement> xNames;

xNames = xDoc.Descendants("name");
```

That will give you a list of the name elements. Then if you want to turn that into a `List<string>` just do this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (XElement element in xNames)
{
    list.Add(element.value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your second xpath starts with `//`. This is an abbreviation for `/descendant-or-self::node()`, which you can see starts with `/`, meaning it searches **from the root of the document**, whatever the context in which you use it.

You probably want one of:

```
var rowName = row.SelectSingleNode("name");
```

to find the `name` nodes that are *immediate children* of the `row`, or

```
var rowName = row.SelectSingleNode(".//name");
```

to find `name` nodes *anywhere under`the`row`. Note the`.` in this second xpath that causes the xpath to start from the context node.

Answer (score 3):

Use a relative path e.g. `string rowName = row.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your second XPath query:

```
//row
```

This has a global scope, so no matter where you call it from, it will select *all* `row` elements.

It should work if you replace your expression with:

```
.//row
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use SelectSingleNode, and then the InnerText property.

```
var rowName = row.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
        doc.LoadXml(xml);

            foreach(XmlNode row in doc.SelectNodes("/rows/row"))
            {
                string rowName = row.SelectSingleNode("//name").InnerText.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: That will cause the same problem as I had to begin with, sorry

Comment: Let me rephrase lol, I got rid of the /rows and just did it as //row and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Let's take an example of `XML` as below to fetch data of document using `XPath`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>    <!DOCTYPE svg (View Source for full doctype...)>   <!-- Created with AIM.   -->   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1668.75 1074.75" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" zoomAndPan="magnify" version="1.0" contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css">   can't read ": no such element in array    <g id="#1" class="track" />  <g id="#5" class="dedication">  <metadata>   <meta name="color">Red</meta>    </metadata>   <text fill="#181818">AQWSD</text>    </g>  <g id="#6" class="wordasword">  <metadata>   <meta name="epigraph">Output 1</meta>    <meta name="color">Red</meta>    <meta name="refentry">qandadiv</meta>    </metadata>   <paramdef fill="none" />    <text fill="#181818">0.35</text>    </g>  <g id="#7" class="wordasword">  <metadata>   <meta name="epigraph">Output 2</meta>    <meta name="color">Red</meta>    <meta name="refentry">calloutlist</meta>    <meta name="screen">common></meta>   </metadata>   <path fill="none" />    <text fill="#181818">lineannotation</text>    <text fill="#181818">WHO</text>    <paramdef fill="#232323" />    </g>  <g id="#" class="wordasword">  <metadata>   <meta name="epigraph">Output 3</meta>    <meta name="color">Red</meta>    <meta name="refentry">calloutlist</meta>    <meta name="screen">common></meta>    </metadata>   <path fill="none" />    <text fill="#181818">lineannotation</text>    <text fill="#181818">WHO</text>    <paramdef fill="#232323" />    </g>   </svg>
```

**I have checked and build the code below that is working correctly.**

Below is run-time value of above mentioned XML document as `xmlContent`.

```
 var xmlContent = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG
1.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd\">\r\n<!--Created with AIM.-->\r\n<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 1668.75 1074.75\">\r\ncan't read \": no such element in array<g id=\"#1\" class=\"track\"></g><g id=\"#5\" class=\"dedication\">\r\n<metadata>\r\n<meta name=\"color\">Red</meta>\r\n</metadata>\r\n<text fill=\"#181818\">AQWSD</text>\r\n</g>\r\n<g id=\"#6\" class=\"wordasword\">\r\n<metadata>\r\n<meta name=\"epigraph\">Output 1</meta>\r\n<meta name=\"color\">Red</meta>\r\n<meta name=\"refentry\">qandadiv</meta>\r\n</metadata>\r\n<paramdef fill=\"none\" />\r\n<text fill=\"#181818\">0.35</text>\r\n</g>\r\n<g id=\"#7\" class=\"wordasword\">\r\n<metadata>\r\n<meta name=\"epigraph\">Output 2</meta>\r\n<meta name=\"color\">Red</meta>\r\n<meta name=\"refentry\">calloutlist</meta>\r\n<meta name=\"screen\">common></meta>\r\n</metadata>\r\n<path fill=\"none\" />\r\n<text fill=\"#181818\">lineannotation</text>\r\n<text fill=\"#181818\">WHO</text>\r\n<paramdef fill=\"#232323\"/>\r\n</g>\r\n<g id=\"#\" class=\"wordasword\">\r\n<metadata>\r\n<meta name=\"epigraph\">Output 3</meta>\r\n<meta name=\"color\">Red</meta>\r\n<meta name=\"refentry\">calloutlist</meta>\r\n<meta name=\"screen\">common></meta>\r\n</metadata>\r\n<path fill=\"none\"/>\r\n<text fill=\"#181818\">lineannotation</text>\r\n<text fill=\"#181818\">WHO</text>\r\n<paramdef fill=\"#232323\"/>\r\n</g>\r\n</svg>";


XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(xmlContent);

//Select all g Nodes of class wordasword that have color red in metadata>meta 
var gNodesOnClassOfColorRed = xml.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='g'][@class='wordasword'][*[local-name()='metadata'][*[local-name()='meta'][@name='color'] = 'Red']]").Cast<XmlNode>();

foreach (XmlNode gNode in gNodesOnClassOfColorRed)
{
    var metadata = gNode.SelectSingleNode("*[local-name()='metadata']").Cast<XmlNode>();    //Fetch metadata of g tag

    //Fetch epigraph value from meta tag from metadata
    var epigraph = metadata.Cast<XmlNode>()
                    .Where(z => z.Attributes.Count != 0 && z.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name") != null && z.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value.Trim().ToLower() == "epigraph")
                    .Select(p => p.InnerText).FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine(epigraph);
}
```

**The above code will fetch the `epigraph` value from `Metadata`. The output of the `epigraph` value will be printed as**

> Output 1, Output 2, Output 3

**The below code will fetch the `text tag` list of all `g tags` where is `xml` is same as above**

```
var elementList = (XmlNodeList)xml.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='g'][@class='wordasword'][*[local-name()='text']]");

foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in elementList)     //g
{
    XmlNodeList textList = (XmlNodeList)xmlNode.SelectNodes("*[local-name()='text']");
}
```