# Get element from xml string in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have following xml string which is best way to read `tempTxnId`

```
<MMP>
  <MERCHANT>
    <RESPONSE>
      <url>https://test</url>
      <param name="ttype">NBFund</param>
      <param name="tempTxnId">100000552091</param>
      <param name="token">5PY8i988hsEqLftDl7V2m69y5VGp</param>
      <param name="txnStage">1</param>
    </RESPONSE>
  </MERCHANT>
</MMP>
```

Comment: Google LINQ To XML

Answer (score 0):

first you'd have to know a little about XML. namely:

- Reading XML, what is a tag, node, attribute, etc. A cursory search on the web for "Learn XML" produced: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/
- The next step is understanding a little XPath. XPath is a query language used on XML. again, web search: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp
- The third piece to this puzzle is how to incorporate this into C#. a short web search of "read xml c# xpath" revealed this tidbit. [Using XPath to parse an XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299069/using-xpath-to-parse-an-xml-document)

this is a basic web search research project. this is the way I learned most of my programming, by searching the web, reading, learning.

Learning to research is probably the most important skill of a modern day programmer.